# How can I traverse a nested document in MongoDB and return the sub-tree?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document with the following structure in MongoDB:

```
{
    "k1": {
        "k11": {<extended-sub-document-11>},
        "k12": {<extended-sub-document-12>}
    },
    "k2": {
        "k21": {<extended-sub-document-21>}
    }
}
```

How can I fetch the entire object at `k12`? The `find` mechanism requires me to provide a value against which to match. But here, I simply want to traverse the path `k1/k12` and retrieve the entire sub-document at that key.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try :  `db.collection.find({}, { "k1.k12": 1})` or `db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      k12: "$k1.k12"
    }
  }
])`

Comment: This returns the ancestor keys of `k12` as well, but if this is the only way, I can work around it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean by ancestor keys ? Is `k1` ? then did you try aggregation query ?

Comment: Perfect. The aggregation is just what I need. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#projection) in `.find()` you can try as like below :

```
db.collection.find({}, { "k1.k12": 1})
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vreF157iGk5)

**Note :** You would only get values/object of `k12` but as it's nested in `k1`, In the output you would see same structure with just `k12` object in `k1` like : `{k1: {k12: {...}}}`.

Using aggregation's [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) stage :

```
db.collection.aggregate([ { $project: {_id :0,  k12: "$k1.k12" } } ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-L1Bb_FS0fi)

By using aggregation `$project` which is way more powerful than projection in `.find()` you can assign a field's value to a field. In the above query we're  assigning value at `k1.k12` to a field `k12` using `$` (Which helps to get value of referenced field).